# spring boot RestController from maven dependency does not work

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, dependency-management

I have a following controller in my microservices-core project:

```
package com.XYZ.microservices.core.api.version;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/version")
public class VersionController {

    @Autowired
    private VersionService versionService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public Version getVersion() {
        return versionService.getVersion();
    }
}
```

I have another project called product-service. I am importing microservices-core to product-service like this:

```
dependencies {
        compile("com.XYZ:microservices-core:1.0.0-RELEASE")
        ...
}
```

Now, I am initializing product-service application like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The classes in microservices-core are available in product-service. But I am not able to GET localhost:8080/version when I run product-service. Can someone help?

Comment: What's the error you are getting ? 404 ?

Comment: yeah, whitelabel error page

Comment: Can you add the spring trace that you see on the output when you start the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is your main application class package is not in the same package as the controller class.

Add `ComponentScan` annotation to your main class to scan all subpackages for components:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.XYZ.microservices.core"})
public class ProductServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: that does it. Thank you very much sir! :)